# How can I uninstall Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I have installed ubuntu netbook edition via a bootable-USB and upgraded ubuntu to 11.04 via network connection. I want to uninstall ubuntu and restore windows 7 starter but I cannot find the partition. Have I inadvertently deleted the partition? I remember creating one before installing ubuntu but I cannot seem to remember how I did so. How do I go about uninstalling it? I have windows 7 starter on a CD - would it be usable if I created a botable USB with windows starter and restore my netbook?

Answer (score 0):

Boot to the install CD. You can ten in the partitioner delete all of your partitions and create an NEW one for Ubuntu. A recovery CD may not work unless you create a blank NTFS partition in the beginning of the drive with gparted(See software center). If it is an install CD, easy.